# Error uploading image

Tags: php

This is a pretty heavy script for myself, quite advanced but good progress so far for my charities website! All works, however I've recently implemented to upload the file then I wish to store the file location to my database.

The following PHP code is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'] ) ) {
        $host_name  = "dbXXXXXXXX";
        $database   = "dbXXXXXXXX";
        $user_name  = "dbXXXXXXXX";
        $password   = "XXXXXXXXXX";

        $db = mysqli_connect( $host_name, $user_name, $password, $database );   

        if (!$db)   
        {   
            die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());   
        }

        // example of inserting data into that table: 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO BananzaNews(title,newsDate,imagePath,content,websitePath) " 
             . " VALUES( ?, NOW(), ?, ?, ? )"; 

        $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql ); 
        if (!$stmt) 
        { 
            die("Failed to prepare statement: " . $sql); 
        } 

        // here I only get the title, website, and summary from the <form> 
        // that posted to this page: 
        $title = $_POST["news_title"]; 
        $desc  = $_POST["news_content"];
        $more  = $_POST["news_websitePath"];

        if (!empty($_FILES["file"])) {
            $allowedExt = array("png","jpg","jpeg","gif");
            //echo $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            //echo "uploading...";

            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
                die("An error occurred uploading ".$_FILES["file"]["error"].": ".$sql);
            }
                else
            {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $img = "Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
        } else {
            die("An error occurred uploading ".$_FILES["file"]["error"].": ".$sql);
        }

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $title, $img, $desc, $more ); 

        if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) 
        { 
            die("Execution of bound statement failed: " . $stmt->error); 
        } 

        echo "Inserted {$stmt->affected_rows} correctly.<hr/>"; 

        $db->close();
    }
?>
```

The error message being displayed:

> An error occurred uploading : INSERT INTO
>   BananzaNews(title,newsDate,imagePath,content,websitePath) VALUES( ?,
>   NOW(), ?, ?, ? )

**Additional** I should note that I've specified the full path due to this page being located on admin.website and I just want it on the main site.

### Requested Additional

**HTML Form Code:**

```
<form class="Form" action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Row">
            <!--<label>Enter the RaffleBananza news title.</label>-->
            <input type="text" name="news_title" id="news_title" placeholder="Enter News Title">
        </div>
        <div class="ClearFix"></div>
        <div class="Row">
            <!--<label>Upload a cover image to be shown on preview mode.</label>-->
            <div id="file">Choose file</div>
            <input type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <div class="ClearFix"></div>
        <div class="Row">
            <!--<label>Enter the short description seen on the preview mode.</label>-->
            <textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="news_content" id="news_content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="ClearFix"></div>
        <div class="Row">
            <!--<label>Enter the page URL to see the full details.</label>-->
            <input type="text" name="news_websitePath" id="news_websitePath" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('GMT');echo "/news/".date("d")."/".date("m")."/".date("Y")."/";?>">
        </div>
        <div class="ClearFix"></div>
        <div class="Row">
            <input name="submitted" type="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

### Modifications Made

Website path is now localized.

Comment: What does your form look like?  Why are you putting the SQL statement in the error showing a failed upload?  Also, you can't move a file to a web address, it needs a filepath within your current system.

Comment: ^^^ Yes please post the form. Often it's a missing `enctype='multipart/form-data` attribute when a key is not found in `$_FILES` (which this apparently is despite the misleading SQL in the error message)

Comment: As noted by @MichaelBerkowski `enctype='multipart/form-data` should be added to your `<form>`. It is required when uploading files.

Comment: You seem to be missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` within your `<form` tag. as: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="Form" action="index.php" method="post">`

Comment: Well it is now submitting to the database once again however the file is not uploading. I'll  have a little play around and see what happens :)

Comment: Make sure the path is correct and that the folder(s) have the correct permissions set to write to.

Comment: I don't know where your server is located, but most don't have a `Desktop` folder.  Check your locations for the move file and make sure it's relevant to the server.

Comment: "Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/" is my specified path. This page is located on admin. sub-domain. I'd like to upload to: http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/

Comment: If the script is in your htdoc root, the path seems like it should work.

Comment: Desktop needs to be there, this is where I am working on the page [here:](http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/index.php) and want the thumbs under this folder.

Comment: @Fred-ii- is right since the folder of your script is in `Desktop`, you want to remove that from your file path name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**about absolute and relative paths**

as mentioned in the comments, you should remove the `Desktop` part of your path, and here is why

since your path does not begin with `/`:

```
"Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

it will be evaluated by php as *relative* to the folder containing the executed php script, which is the folder `Desktop` as you mention in the comments:

`http://rafflebananza.com/Desktop/index.php`

that means that php will actually think you want to save your image to this place:

```
"[root]/Desktop/Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs/[...]"
```

which I don't think is the case.

you may either **remove Desktop**, or use your absolute path to Desktop. To find this, you can use [`getcwd();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

then, your paths will look something like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Desktop/...
/home/rafflebananza/Desktop/...
```

remember:

- absolute paths `must` be prepended with `/`
- relative paths `must not` be prepended with `/`
- `./` refers to current folder
- `../` refers to parent folder
- you can stack them `./../folderInParentFolder/file.php`

Comment: I performed an echo test of `echo getcwd();` which resulted in /homepages/32/d*********/htdocs/adminInserted

Comment: @TimMarshall if `Desktop` is at the same level as `asminInserted` your absolute path should be `/homepages/32/d*********/htdocs/Desktop/IMG/BananzaNews/Thumbs`

Comment: of course. it's the unix symbol for `up one level`.